# how and when to use a preposition for the verb ' make it '?

Tags: prepositions, verbs, expressions

Considering the use of this verb meaning in : **'manage to arrive'**  . How and when do I use the preposition **'to'** ?

Please take a look at the following sentences and explain which one makes sense in both examples to mean in the mentioned definition.

> 1. Sorry, I can't **make it home** for dinner tonight, I've got my hands full with a bunch of work.
> 2. Sorry, I can't **make it to home** for dinner tonight, I've got my hands full with a bunch of work.

Here is another one :

> 1. There was heavy traffic but I finally **made it to work**.
> 2. There was heavy traffic but I finally **made it work**.

Comment: "made it to work" means you finally arrived at your work. not sure about the second one though.

Comment: "made it work" implies there was a problem, but you found an acceptable solution. _I didn't have the blackberries the recipe called for, but I made it work. I used raspberries instead_

Comment: _Home_ is not a noun in your first example; it's an _adverb of place,_ and as a result can't be the object of the preposition _to._ You can find a handy list of these adverbs [**here**](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/33653/192771) on our sister site ELU.

Comment: "my hands full with a bunch of works" is not idiomatic, the noun *work* is normally an uncountable noun, unless it refers to pieces of fine art, musical compositions, or literary works  e.g.  *The works of Beethoven cover a period of thirty years*, factories (BrEng) *The steel works*, and road repair work (BrEng *roadworks*) https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/work

Comment: On the other hand, **with a bunch of work** is idiomatic, and perfectly correct :)

Answer (score 2):

- ***I can't make it home*** CORRECT

This means you are unable to reach this destination. *Home* could refer to the  building, or the area where you live; e.g., village, city, country. When used as an adverb of place, *home* requires no preposition

An Australian holidaymaker: ***I can't wait to get back home*** *(home = Melbourne, Australia)*

- ***I can't make it to home***  UNLIKELY but not impossible

In this sentence we have to identify what *home* might be referring to. It could be short for [*home base*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/home%20base) (think of a baseball player running to *home base*) or the *home plate*

> With the Yankees prepared for the long play, Taylor instead bunts, allowing Hayes *[**to make it to home**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Major_League_(film)#Plot)* safely and win the game.

- ***There was  heavy traffic but I finally made it to work*** CORRECT

This means the speaker managed to arrive at his or her workplace despite the traffic. *Work* and *workplace* are nouns, and the preposition *to* is used to express motion or a direction toward a point or thing.

- ***There was heavy traffic but I finally made it work*** INCORRECT

This sentence *is* grammatical but it has a completely different meaning. It means that the speaker managed to make something *work* i.e *function* despite the heavy traffic. In other words, the speaker repaired something that was broken or not functioning properly. And in the sentence,  *work* is used a verb

> *My watch is broken, can you make it work again?*
>   *His phone doesn't work unless he goes to a high point*

Comment: We would say "There was heavy traffic" not "*a* heavy traffic" in that context.

Comment: @TRomano you're right. A slip up, others would have edited the post, or just left a comment. Anyway, thanks for telling me. And I don't suppose there's any chance of you retracting your downvote, is there?

Comment: Tnx a lot Mari ....

Comment: @YazdanSamieiPoor Oh, thank you. I'm glad the answer helped you in some way.

Answer (score 1):

***[Make it](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/make+it)***  (informal) is an idiomatic expression with different connotations. It is also used with the meaning:

> - ***to manage to arrive at a place or go to an event***. *She made it to the airport just in time to catch her plane. We're having a party on Saturday - can you make it?*

(Cambridge Dictionary of American Idioms)

The preposition "to"  is generally used. It is not used  in "*make it home"* as "*home*" is not preceded by the preposition to as in "I'm going  home".

Comment: make it to the house; make it to the apartment; make it to my home, but just make it home.

Comment: what about "made it work" in the second example? im curious about it.

Comment: @Will - made it work sounds like you repaired something and made it function. You'd say I made it to work if you mean that you went to your workplace.

Comment: @AbsoluteBeginner So you mean the preposition "to" always accompanies "make it" other than when it comes with "home" ? Aren't there any other exceptions which violate this rule? Is "home" the only one which comes without "to" ?

Comment: @YazdanSamieiPoor - "Home" is a special case in English, which functions like an adverb.  "I am going home", but never "I am going work" or "I am going restaurant".  I think it is the only one that works like that.

Comment: @stangdon Nope, _home_ is not the only such _adverb of place._ You can find lists of them here and there. [**Here,**](http://www.momswhothink.com/reading/list-of-adverbs.html) for instance.

Comment: @stangdon I agree that "home" is a *special case* because it can  either be an **adverb** or a **noun**. When it's a noun we can place a determiner such as *my* e.g. "my home is not far", you couldn't say that with *outside* "my outside is not far from here" (*outside* is listed as an adverb of place in P.E.Dant's link)

Comment: @P.E.Dant - True that it's not the only adverb of place, but I think it's the only one that is also a noun, as Mari-Lou says.  I can *go home* or *to a home* or *to his home*, but while I can *go outside*  I can't go to "a somewhere" or "the abroad".

Comment: @stangdon When I finished having my home painted, **the outside** was pink. **The inside** was painted and papered in a variety of colors and patterns: **the upstairs** is mostly papered in flocked Victorian papers, while **the downstairs** is colored in muted mustards and pumpkins.

Answer (score 0):

When **make it** is used to mean "attend an event" or "reach a place or destination"

> I can't make it *to the party*.
>
> I can't make it *to the office*.
>
> I can't make it *to work*.
>
> I can't make it onto the plane|boat|raft|solid ice|steep bank|diving board|gangplank|elevator|A-list...
>
> I can't make it *home*.
>
> I can't make it *there*.
>
> I can't make it *over*.
>
> I can't make it *out*.
>
> I can't make it *up*.
>
> I can't make it *down*.
>
> I can't make it *across*.
>
> I can't make it *through*.

you will notice that the complement sometimes is a prepositional phrase and sometimes a simple locative. I suppose a modern grammarian would call the simple locative an intransitive preposition or intransitive adposition. It used to be called an adverb.  It establishes the location in space or the nature of the movement through space.

However, whether the preposition **to** is required or not has nothing to do with the verb **make it**. The prepositional phrases are governed by their own grammatical rules independent of the verb.

Comment: based on what you has mentioned , it is a literary custom to use or not use " to " which we have to memorise it . Isn't it ?

Comment: You have to learn how to use transitive locative prepositions and intransitive locative adpositions.  These are not literary conventions but grammatical rules. You do have to commit them to memory, either by conversing with native speakers on a regular basis, or by some rote book exercise.

Comment: @YazdanSamieiPoor It might be easier to understand if you think of it like this: the preposition _to_ can only take a noun or NP as its object, and _home, there, up, down, across_ &c. aren't nouns. (_Home_ is an adverb of place here.)

Comment: **I can't make it up** is a bit ambiguous, it could also mean "I can't invent/create a story or a lie". And then there's the "I'll **make it up** to you" when you want to say you're "sorry".

Comment: *I can't make it over* is also ambiguous, and *I can't make it out*.  Good thing we have contexts, or English-speakers would be in bad shape.

Comment: Oh, well it's a downvote from me. If you don't want to mention the possible issues of ambiguity.

Comment: The ambiguity is irrelevant when all I'm doing is giving a list of barebones examples without context.  And the examples are about the difference between transitive prepositions and intransitive adpositions (aka adverbs of place), not about the verb **make it**.  Apparently you have not understood the answer.  OP's question actually has nothing to do with the verb **make it**, although he assumed it did.

Comment: ...intransitive locative adpositions (aka adverbs of place)...

Comment: The meaning is still ambiguous. There's a hill, I am old, my knees are not once what they were, I don't think I would say "I can't make it up" I would instead say: **I can't make it up there.** I don't know what the grammar rule is, if indeed there is any, but just saying: "I can't make it up" sounds too abrupt for *my* ears, and I'm 50 years old. No longer a spring chicken.

Comment: I am not disputing the ambiguity. I am dismissing it as irrelevant here, since the answer is *not* about the specific meanings of the phrase **make it** in combination with prepositions and adpositions.  The phrase "I can't make it up" is a perfectly idiomatic sentence one might hear from the lips of a native speaker, who can't get up a ladder, or who can't get up to Boston this Thanksgiving.  There's no need to supply an object to **up** in context. *Sorry, I can't make it up this year.*  We would not have to say "up to Boston" or "up there" , though we could.